# shortcuts to select text in terminal

Tags: command-line

I was wondering if there are shortcuts for selecting some text in terminal, just similar to holding shift and type arrow key in editing a text file in a text editor. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I'm assuming you are referring to Gnome Terminal.

No - there isnt a Copy and Paste mechanism using just the keyboard - you can use various short-cuts to paste (depending upon your Ubuntu version) i.e. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> , <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste text in the clipboard.

However, if you type `screen` you enter the terminal emulator which allows you to select, copy and paste text using just the keyboard.

To select (copy):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> together followed by <kbd>Escape</kbd>.  This puts you into Copy mode.
Using the cursor keys move to the beginning of the text you want to copy.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Now move to the end of the text to be copied.  Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To Paste:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> together followed by <kbd>]</kbd>.

Comment: My question is more about selecting text not about copying and pasting.

Comment: I prefer using keys to select text instead of using mouse or touchpad.

Comment: nope - I must be thick! still dont understand - do you want to discuss this in chat?

Comment: Thanks! In a text editor, one can select text by pressing down SHIFT, and simultaneously pressing -> or <- keys. But in gnome terminal, this will not work.

Comment: how complicated for such a simple task... I'm disappointed :(

Comment: What about terminator? is there a no-screen solution?

Comment: FWIW, there is a better description of how to use screen over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312213/how-do-i-copy-text-from-my-xterm-without-a-mouse

Comment: I'm curious: why would you want to select text, if not to copy/paste...?

Comment: In e.g. ConEmu terminal you can use SHIFT to select other text from the terminal text!

Comment: @rsenna, the OP wants to be able to select the text without the mouse/trackpad. That's the topic. Yes, once you've selected some text in the terminal you probably want to copy it - but the OP already knows how to copy/paste via the keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late for the party but yes there is a way.

1. Replace the rodent with number pad navigation.

   Settings -> Universal Access -> Pointing & Clicking ->
   Enable Mouse Keys

   You can now use the <kbd>4</kbd> to go left, <kbd>8</kbd> to go up, <kbd>5</kbd> to click etc. (make sure <kbd>NumLock</kbd> is OFF).

   NOTE: For this to work you need a NumberPad.
2. Moving the mouse with the number pad is going to be dog slow so lets fix that next. See man page for `xkbset` for details.

   `sudo apt-get install xkbset`

   `xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2`

   Now you should be able to use the NumberPad to move your cursor at a reasonable speed, so move it to the terminal where you want to select the text.
3. To select the text in the terminal to the right of the pointer:

   `Ctrl+Shift+5+6`

   This is equivalent to mouse click=5, go right=6

   To select to the right of the cursor:

   `Ctrl+Shift+5+4`

Answer (score 0):

In `gnome-terminal` running bash as default shell, you can hit `c-x` twice (`c-` same as `ctrl-`) to select the last typed text.

Refer to [bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Line-Editing) for more.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. To me it seems clear that the OP wants to be able to select any text in the terminal in the same way as you would be able to with a mouse - not just copy a previous input.