# How to disable or reorder gnome-terminal right-click context menu?

Tags: gnome-terminal, context-menu

[image: gnome terminal context menu image]

I'm using Gnome Terminal 3.6.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

On my trackpad I'm frequently accidentally opening a new terminal (even though I've disabled tap-to-click), I think the prominent placement of 'Open Terminal' here is to blame.  Can I remove that entry or re-order them?  It would be great to have Copy come first and Paste second?  I use those much more often that opening a tab or terminal (intentionally).

*update*

I can duplicate the behavior (in 13.10) with a mouse- right clicking and dragging diagonally right and down will open a new terminal, but only if done quickly. If I right click and pause then I have to left click the menu options as expected.

*update 2*

It's starting to become more clear: there is an intentional feature of the right click menu that allows a right click and hold followed by the release of the right click on the context menu item of choice, which coexists with the right click release followed by a selection of the menu item and second right or left click.

The problem for me is when I'm intending to right click release and then select a menu item and a perform a second click.  If the cursor is already moving down and right, or if I begin to make that move before releasing the right click, I get the undesired new terminal.  I may be unconsciously trying to optimize the operation by getting a running start, or it is just random mouse movement.

Comment: Can you accept a solution?

Answer (score 2):

In order to disable or reorder the gnome-terminal context menu, you should try editing the **terminal.xml** file located in **/usr/share/gnome-terminal/** directory.

**1)** Make a backup of the terminal.xml file. 
Open a Terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

- `cd /usr/share/gnome-terminal/`
- `sudo cp -p terminal.xml terminal.xml.bak`

**2)** Edit the terminal.xml file with your favorite editor. **eg: nano**

- `sudo nano -c /usr/share/gnome-terminal/terminal.xml`

Regarding to your question you can comment the lines for the ***PopupNewTerminal PopupNewTab PopupCloseTab PopupCloseWindow***  menus. **(Lines 88 to 93)**

[image]

You can comment those lines with `<!-- lines -->` symbols.

[image]

To save the changes in nano.. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Exit or Close the Terminal window and open it again to see the changes.

**BEFORE:**

[image]

**AFTER:**

[image]

This is just an example, you can comment, delete or change the order in the menus **(put the PopupCopy and PopupPaste menus before the PopupNewTerminal)** in the file.

Just in case... please remember you have a backup of the *terminal.xml*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any idea where this is located in gnome-terminal 3.28?

Answer (score 0):

No, the order of the menu items cannot be changed by any settings, nor can it be disabled. If disabling tap-to-click does not work, you should file a bug report against the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package. You can do that by running `ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` in your terminal.

Comment: Actually I can duplicate the behavior (in 13.10) with a mouse- right clicking and dragging diagonally right and down will open a new terminal, but only if done quickly.  If I right click and pause then I have to left click the menu options as expected.

Comment: Of course (and no, the pause is irrelevant, I can hold the right-click down for 10 minutes and then release on "Open Terminal" and a new terminal will open), a mouse and a touchpad are both pointing devices. How you are managing to accidentally right click on the touchpad though, is beyond me.

Comment: It's intentional?  Any way to disable it?

Comment: I now know I wasn't accidentally right-clicking, I was releasing the right button a fraction of a second after beginning to move the mouse diagonally right and down to select Copy with a left click instead of making sure the pointer is absolutely still throughout the right click process.  Or at other times I was already moving the mouse diagonally right and down and then right clicked mid move also intending to select Copy or Paste.

Answer (score 0):

The solution so far looks to be to untrain the right-click-release, menu select, click operation (maybe that came from  Windows?), and just do the right click and hold and then release on the desired menu item- making sure the cursor is still would slow things down too much.

I believe click-hold-move-release is worse for carpal tunnel/repetitive strain, but so perhaps is having to close a bunch unwanted terminal windows.

Another possible solution would be if I could move the cursor from the keyboard and copy and paste vim-like, [shortcuts to select text in terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55162/shortcuts-to-select-text-in-terminal) suggests *screen* (though the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Escape</kbd> command to enter copy mode is not ideal)

Comment: Or just use the keybindings for copy/paste, and the mouse to select the text, instead of using the menu at all.