# Make p on Gnome Terminal right-click menu trigger Paste not Preferences?

Tags: gnome-terminal

Recent versions of `gnome-terminal` have a "Preferences" menu item on the right-click menu that interferes with `p` choosing "Paste" when the menu is up. My long-term-ingrained habit of right-click-and-press-p dislikes this cheese relocation. :-) Is there a way to make it paste instead? (For instance: Removing "Preferences" would probably do it.) I never expect to want to use that Preferences menu item.

I realize I could use the keyboard shortcut instead, but habits are habits, and some things I do involving pasting to terminals work fairly well if I have one hand on the mouse and the other on the keyboard. I use the mouse left-handed, and can't <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd> with my right-hand only.

I've tried:

- [This question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453906/how-to-disable-or-reorder-gnome-terminal-right-click-context-menu) talk about modifying `/usr/share/gnome-terminal/` but that file doesn't exist anywhere on my system (nor, as far as I can tell, anything like it).
- I also can't find anything with `gconf-editor` or `dconf-editor`.

Comment: Probably little you can do apart from filing a bug, or editing source code yourself. Unfortunately, there is sometimes little care for keyboard support.

Comment: @vanadium - Heh, at one point I was going to say "I mean, worst case I could edit the source and build it myself..." and I'm not sure why I didn't say that in the end. :-D