# Terminal supporting Keyboard Mark Mode (like Windows 10)?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Is there an alternative terminal for Ubuntu that supports something like the Windows 10 "mark mode"?

It allows selecting text and copying to the system clipboard with the keyboard only.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Windows10GetsAFreshCommandPromptAndLotsOfHotkeys.aspx

---

Update: I found [termite](https://github.com/thestinger/termite/) which can do this but unfortunately is missing tabs. Also setting it up is quite painful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [shortcuts to select text in terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55162/shortcuts-to-select-text-in-terminal)

Comment: @A.B. I've read that question and Terminal can't do it - that's why I am asking about an alternative terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome terminal already allows selecting text with mouse and copying with Ctrl + Shift + C . Pasting is done with Ctrl + Shift + V.

Comment: Yes but I'd like to select with the keyboard - see mark mode.